# What is the fastest vertical checkmate for both castlings?

Tags: checkmate, problems, castling, records

I wish to know the fastest possible castling checkmate, both queenside and kingside, that is vertical.

See my question about [horizontal checkmates.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23847/)

Comment: Interesting. We should keep separate records for black and white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mate in 6.0 for kingside.

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1 "]
1. e4 e6 2. Bc4 Bd6 3. Ke2 Qg5 4. Kf3 Nh6 5. Bxe6 fxe6 6. Qe2 O-O#
```

And 5.5 for queenside, even faster.

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1 "]
1. d4 Nc6 2. Nc3 Nxd4 3. Qxd4 e5 4. Qc4 Ke7 5. Bg5+ Kd6 6. O-O-O#
```

This should be fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a mate (in 7) for kingside castling:

```
[FEN ""]

1. e4 f5 2. f3 fxe4 3. fxe4 Kf7 4. Qh5+ Kf6 5. Nh3 a6 6. Bc4 a5 7. O-O#
```

Answer (score 2):

mate in seven for queenside castling:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 d5 2. d3 dxe4 3. Nc3 Kd7 4. Bh6 Kd6 5. dxe4+ Ke5 6. Qh5+ Kd4 7. O-O-O#
```

Might be worth checking whether it gets any faster if black is the one to castle.